# Inserting text and link dynamically into another webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage that will have a bunch of external links on it. When the user clicks one, they are taken to a Disclaimer page that informs them that they are leaving this site. They have a choice to go back or continue. I want one Disclaimer page that is populated with the outgoing URL and the text of the specific link that was clicked on previous page. Is it possible to insert these elements in a separate webpage?

Comment: You could do something clever with the querystring to "pass the text of the specific link that was clicked."

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. the `base64_encode` allows a url to be safely passed using the `GET` method. Then you must check if that key exists in your destination page and then redirect back if the user says they don't want to leave the site and redirect forward if the user does want to leave the site.

```
<?php     
    // Place this on your page
    $currentPage = base64_encode(curPageURL());
    $outgoingPage = base64_encode("someurl.com");

    // creates a link that passes on the page that it came from and the page to go to if the user chooses to do so  
    echo "<a href='disclaimer.php?return={$currentPage}&go={$outgoingPage}'>Leave Page</a>";

?>

<?php
    // when the button is clicked to cancel leaving the page
    if(isset($_GET["return"])) {
     header("Location: ".base64_decode($_GET["return"]));  
    } else {
     header("Location: someDefaultPage.php");  
    }

    // and if the button to leave the page is clicked
    if(isset($_GET["go"])) {
     header("Location: ".base64_decode($_GET["go"]));  
    } else {
     header("Location: someDefaultPage.php");  
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Bluehound! I'll give this a go ... Im a n00b to deeper scripting, so I appreciate the help!